# How to copy Location Country field value from Parent object to Child object field default value?

Tags: 7, location

I use Parent and Child content types with a Field used in both types.

I would like Drupal to automatically propagate the Field value from Parent value to the Child field default value.

How to do this ?
I am interested specificaly in an example for Location>Country field.

I use node reference or organic groups modules to set up Parent<->Child relationships.

Comment: Do you simply want to copy parent's value to child and allow them to change independently?

Comment: @AgA Child objects almost always have the location of parent object. I would like to use parent's values as defaults and to allow to change child's values independently only for certain roles. I need these values in child objects because I use child objects in views but I would like to filter on location properly and for performance reasons I would like location to be available directly from child objects. I would like also to limit data entry so that location can be entered once for all child objects (in the parent object).

Comment: Then the simplest and easiest way is to go for @BetaRide's answer. Hardly any work you'll need to do to implement it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guess you want this to take place, when you create (aka save to db) a new node. You could do this in [hook_node_presave](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7).

Answer (score 0):

There is a contributed module [nodelocation_relationship](http://drupal.org/project/nodelocation_relationship) that helps with this but it is currently available for Drupal 6 only.

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 7 use node reference url http://drupal.org/project/nodereference_url

When a new child is created it will reference-back to the parent. The parent is passed in the URL.